# Adding the data of different rows which share the same date in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following dataframe in R:

```
      Date        A   B    C

1  2015-01-17     1   NA   1
2  2015-01-18     NA  NA   NA
3  2015-01-19     1   2    3
4  2015-01-19     1   NA   1
...
```

The goal is that different rows having the same date add their values in columns A,B,C:

```
      Date        A   B    C

1  2015-01-17     1   NA   1
2  2015-01-18     NA  NA   NA
3  2015-01-19     2   2    4
...
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Date)%>%
  summarise_at(.,c("A","B","C"),function(x) if(any(!is.na(x)))sum(x,na.rm = T) else NA)


# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Date           A     B     C
  <fct>      <int> <int> <int>
1 2015-01-17     1    NA     1
2 2015-01-18    NA    NA    NA
3 2015-01-19     2     2     4
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2015-01-17", 
"2015-01-18", "2015-01-19"), class = "factor"), A = c(1L, NA, 
1L, 1L), B = c(NA, NA, 2L, NA), C = c(1L, NA, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `sum_` from `hablar`

```
library(hablar)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise_if(is.numeric, sum_)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Date           A     B     C
#  <fct>      <int> <int> <int>
#1 2015-01-17     1    NA     1
#2 2015-01-18    NA    NA    NA
#3 2015-01-19     2     2     4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2015-01-17", 
"2015-01-18", "2015-01-19"), class = "factor"), A = c(1L, NA, 
1L, 1L), B = c(NA, NA, 2L, NA), C = c(1L, NA, 3L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```